# Using Jackson as Jersey client serializer

Tags: jersey, jackson

Is it possible to use Jackson as the serializer/marshaller for JSON data instead of JAXB when using Jersey Client API?

If so how to configure it?

Comment: Interesting question: I have not used client API (yet). Have you asked this on Jersey list(s)? It definitely should be possible to plug message readers/writers, and Jackson jax-rs plug-in implements those interfaces.

Comment: StaxMan, Jersey Client API is not part of the JAX-RS spec. But your right, I should first try asking on the Jersey mailing list.

Comment: For recent Jersey versions like 2.26 please see my answer below.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

OK, I found it out, it turns out to be quite simple after all:

```
ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();
cc.getClasses().add(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
Client clientWithJacksonSerializer = Client.create(cc);
```

The JacksonJsonProvider comes from the jackson-jaxrs package.

Comment: See also swist's answer below, which is even simplier.

Comment: it's now the jackson-jaxrs-json-provider package with newer versions of jackson.

Comment: Is there a way that it 'auto-discovers' the jacksonjson provider?

Answer (score 23):

You may skip the creation of external config and register the provider directly:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(JacksonJsonProvider.class)
```

Answer (score 13):

### Solution with `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider`

Common way how to use Jackson with custom configuration in Jersey client was to use `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` for example like this

```java
JacksonJaxbJsonProvider provider = new JacksonJaxbJsonProvider();
provider.setMapper(yourObjectMapper());
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfig(provider));
```

Unfortunately in **Jersey 2.26** they copied `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` class
from `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider` artifact (Jackson)
to `org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson` artifact (Jersey)
and changed package
from `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json`
to `org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.jackson.jaxrs.json`.

It is still possible to use this approach it's just needed to change `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` import.

Apart from `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` being now in `internal` package drawback is also 
that you must know on which Jersey version your code runs which might be a problem when different dependencies require different Jersey versions.

### Better solution with `ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>`

Better possibility how to configure Jackson in Jersey *client* is to use the same way how it is configured in Jersey *server* which is to create `ObjectMapper` provider like this:

```java
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper = yourObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
        return objectMapper;
    }

}
```

and use it for example like this:

```java
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.register(JacksonFeature.class);  // usually auto-discovered
clientConfig.register(new ObjectMapperProvider());
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
```

If you have both the server and the client you can reuse `ObjectMapperProvider` class.

It seems that this approach works from Jersey version 2.9.

Answer (score 4):

You might also want to try `org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider (jackson-jaxrs 1.6.1)`.

Comment: @landon9720 because it supports JAXB annotations as well as the default Jackson annotations.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into similar issue, but for me none of the suggestions given here worked.
What worked for me was below piece of code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
...

ClientBuilder clientBuilder = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
clientBuilder.register(JacksonFeature.class);
...
Client client = clientBuilder.build();
```

The key change was usage of `JacksonFeature.class` - it comes from `jersey-media-json-jackson-x.yy.jar`

I got clue to use this solution from this article - http://www.baeldung.com/jersey-jax-rs-client

Answer (score 0):

For jersey **2.22.2** and Jackson **2.7.2** gradle dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.7.2")
    compile("org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.22.2")
}
```

Sample client code is:

```
final String    name    = "world";
final Client    client  = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);
final WebTarget target  = client.target("http://localhost:8080").path("hello").path(name);
final Message   message = target.request().get(Message.class);

System.out.println(message.getWelcomeMessage()); // hello world
```