# A message body writer for Java type, class net.sf.json.JSONObject, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found

Tags: json, rest, jersey

I am using jersey client for making call to rest webservice.

My webservice is consuming the json, so i need to put json in making call to my webservice provider.

I am doing it in below way.

```
    JSONObject object=new JSONObject();
    object.put("name", employee.getName());
    object.put("empId", employee.getEmpId());
    object.put("organizationName", employee.getOrganizationName());


ClientResponse response = service.path("rest").path("vtn").path("addEmplyee")
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class, object);
```

but i am getting the below exception:

> 09:52:01,625 ERROR [[mvc-dispatcher]] Servlet.service() for servlet
>   mvc-dispatcher threw exception
>   **com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class net.sf.json.JSONObject, and MIME media
>   type, application/json, was not found**
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.writeRequestEntity(RequestWriter.java:288)
>           at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:204)
>           at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:147)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:670)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
>           at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:563)
>           at com.nec.jp.pflow.unc.service.EmployeeService.addEmployee(EmployeeService.java:44)
>           at com.nec.jp.pflow.unc.controller.EmployeeController.addCustomer(EmployeeController.java:29)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)

But if i convert my json to string representation like :

```
String input = "{\"name\" : \"" + employee.getName() + "\",\"empId\" : \"" + employee.getEmpId() + "\",\"organizationName\" : \"" + employee.getOrganizationName() + "\"}";

ClientResponse response = service.path("rest").path("vtn").path("addEmplyee")
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class, input);
```

then it is working fine.

Please suggest how can i put my JSON Object without getting the above exception. What is the best way?

Thanks in advance.

---

I got a solution for the above. Now I am making use of jackson-mapper api for converting the POJO to json.

Below is the code snippet.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ClientResponse response = resource.path("rest").path("vtn").path("addEmplyee")
        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class, mapper.writeValueAsString(employee));
```

Comment: If you found a solution, you can post that as the answer and select it yourself. Otherwise, this question looks unanswered.

Answer (score 14):

A better way is to tell `jersey-client` that it may use `jackson` for serialization:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2580315/516188

Pasting the setup:

```
ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();
cc.getClasses().add(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
Client clientWithJacksonSerializer = Client.create(cc);
```

`JacksonJsonProvider` is in the `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider` package.

Answer (score 8):

**Just copying the solution from the question above, just in case someone is looking for answer.**

Use  jackson-mapper api for converting the POJO to json as shown in the code snippet below:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ClientResponse response = resource.path("rest").path("vtn").path("addEmplyee")
        .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class, mapper.writeValueAsString(employee));
```

Comment: better to avoid converting as string inside the method. Most impotantly objectMapper instance also not required if you configured the clientconfig properly.

Answer (score 5):

adding a .toString() worked for me:

```
JSONObject object=new JSONObject();
object.put("name", employee.getName());
object.put("empId", employee.getEmpId());
object.put("organizationName", employee.getOrganizationName());


ClientResponse response = service.path("rest").path("vtn").path("addEmplyee").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(ClientResponse.class,object.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
JSONObject object=new JSONObject();
```

need to provide `@XMLrootElement` Annotation....if you are accessing the web service from remote....i.e XML Mapping..for Model class.

Answer (score 1):

After lot of reading here is the solution which i arrived at :

If you are using JERSEY-CLIENT as specified as below of version 1.9 or higher

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then use the MOXY Jar as specified below of version 2.19 or higher

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
</dependency>
```

And then add the MOXyJsonProvider.class in the Class of Client configuration as shown below :

```
ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();
cc.getClasses().add(MOXyJsonProvider.class);
Client client = Client.create(cc);
```

Now make the required configuration to Client Object to connect to server and execute the request:

```
WebResource webResource = client.resource(*restFulPath*);
Builder builder = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

builder.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
builder.header("Accept ", "application/json");
builder.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

try
{
    String requestData = "*requestInJson*";
    ClientResponse response = null;
    response = builder.post(ClientResponse.class, requestData);
    if (response.getStatus() == 200)
    {
        MappedJsonReportOut res = response.getEntity(MappedJsonReportOut.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the entity() methods to achieve this, as follows:

```
    ClientResponse response = resource.path("rest").path("vtn").path("addEmplyee")
    .entity(employee, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
    .post(ClientResponse.class);
```

or

```
    ClientResponse response = resource.path("rest").path("vtn").path("addEmplyee")
    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
    .entity(employee)
    .post(ClientResponse.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Error Which m getting is little Bit Different But Finally Solution is Work for Me

```
   Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class com.siemens.spring.model.User, and MIME media type, application/json, was not found
    at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:670)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:563)
    at com.siemens.controller.UserRegistration.process(UserRegistration.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:153)
```

And This is Solution Worked for Me :

```
    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = client
            .resource("http://localhost:8080/NewsTickerServices/Siemens/CreateJUser");
    // value added

    ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class,mapper.writeValueAsString(user));//user is object of User Pojo class
```